# Does Excel 365 vba (or 2013) have the vbscript Regular Expression that found in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm considering moving to the cloud, but I use a lot regular expressions in Excel and was curious if Excel 365 had vbscript regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clarify exactly what you mean by "vbscript regular expressions".

In general, "Office 365" usage scenarios include downloading and installing the software on particular machines, at which point it functions like regular Excel 2013.  But you should check your licensing terms before you buy.

If you mean using Office 365 Online via a web browser / tablet etc, then typically Add-Ins, VBA etc will not run:

http://blogs.office.com/2014/04/14/weve-updated-excel-online-whats-new-in-april-2014/

This seems unlikely to change in the future.